# Can I initialize a derived class with an instance of the base class?

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

Example:

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T> {
    public MyList(List<T> list) {
        this = list;  // this is basically what I want, but doesn't work
        base = list;  // this also doesn't work
    }
}
```

Any solutions? Or is what I'm trying to achieve simply a bad idea?

Motivation: I want to add a custom function to a List object.

Comment: For personal future reference: extension methods aren't really that great. From MSDN: "In your code you invoke the extension method with instance method syntax. However, the intermediate language (IL) generated by the compiler translates your code into a call on the static method. Therefore, the principle of encapsulation is not really being violated. In fact, extension methods cannot access private variables in the type they are extending."
I.e., it's simply calling a static function on an instance, but syntactically sugar-coated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you not do:

```
public MyList(List<T> list) : base(list)
```

Alternatively, couldn't you use an extension method on the List object?

Comment: Well I'll be! Yes it's that simple! Thanks!

As for extension methods, I'm sure I could use those as well, but I didn't know what they were until just now...
I'll read up on extension methods and decide later how I will implement it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

If your using .Net framework 3.5, wouldn't it be easier to define an extension method on a list.  Somthing like...

```
public static class MyListExtensionClass
{
    public static void MyList<T>(this List<T> list)
    {
        // Your stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Extension methods were made for exactly this!

Comment: In certain situation this would surely be the way to go. Thanks for the simple example.

Answer (score 0):

public MyList(List list):base(list)

This will call the following constructor of the base class (in this case List):

```
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyList<T> : List<T>
{
  public MyList(List<T> list)
  {
    AddRange(list);
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is my method to do it:

```
    // Function which instantiates a derived class D for a provided base class B,
    // then assigns all class properties that exist in instance B to derived instance D
    public static D DownCast<B, D>(this B baseClass) where D : new()
    {
        var newDerived = new D();
        var properties = baseClass.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (var prop in properties)
        {
            var derivedPropValue = prop.GetValue(baseClass, null);
            var baseProp = baseClass.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
            var hasProperty = baseProp != null;
            if (hasProperty)
            {
                baseProp.SetValue(newDerived, derivedPropValue, null);
            }
        }
        return newDerived;
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't even work for the single example given, that being a list, let alone work in general.